# VS Code - tab size on an empty line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following settings in Visual Studio Code:

`"editor.tabSize": 4`

`"editor.insertSpaces": true`

However when I drop a new line and hit `tab`, the editor is inserting 8 spaces:

[image]

I do not have any extensions enabled. Is there a setting I can modify to make it so tabbing only inserts 4 spaces in my example above?

#### Update

It appears that the tab spacing is affected by lines above. See animation below. If I have a method with curly braces above my variable assignment line, hitting tab does what I would expect and inserts 4 spaces.

[image]

Below is a subset of the TypeScript file for reference. If you comment out the `product$` and `pipe` function, tabbing inserts the number of spaces I would expect.

```
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ProductService {
    productsWithCategory$;
    productsUrl;

    // comment out starting on the line below
    products$ = this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
        .pipe(
            tap(data => console.log('Products: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    // to here

    selectedProduct$ = this.productsWithCategory$

}
```

Comment: Have you verified you have no conflicting extensions? `code --disable-extensions`

Comment: @soulshined Yes. This occurs without any extensions.

Comment: I am stumped then. It seems like it would be an extension issue or formatter, what you have should be working. I don't use extensions really and I can't reproduce with the info you've given. Try with `code --disable-extensions --user-data-dir .\\` and only add those 2 settings

Comment: @soulshined I updated my post. If I have a method with curly braces above my variable assignment line, hitting tab does what I would expect and inserts 4 spaces. Very strange.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting, but I'm not so sure it's the case, because it works with or without additional context for me. I've added lines above and below and a mixture of both and it's not reproducible for me. Is it respective to that code? Meaning, have you tried in another file using the same language (different code)?

Comment: @soulshined I updated my post with a code sample. I imagine that should reproduce the issue for you.

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks. I don't think it has anything to do with that code being there, it's indentation specific to the syntax. I think it's strictly because of the pipe statement because if you turn on `wrappingIntent` to 'same' and then `formatOnType` to true, you will see the native formatter tries to correct the closing `)` for `pipe()` and put it inline with the `products$` variable declaration column. So for some reason, it's not being considered a closed region. It's basically tabbing to where the args are for pipe. This happens with or without the `selectedProduct$` declaration/line.

Comment: I would assume, at this point, it's a legitimate bug (or lack of support) because if you put all the arguments on the same line as the pipe call it works as expected. Unless, someone else sees something I'm missing

Comment: Filed bug [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103720)